# Magento 2: How to Set custom product attribute value on product save

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, custom-attributes, save

i have created an observer, event on before product save to set custom product attribute value, here is my code.

```
etc/adminhtml/events.xml
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_save_before">
        <observer name="product_save_before" instance="Learning\HelloPage\Observer\Productsavebefore" />
    </event>
</config>
```

---

```
Learning/HelloPage/Observer/Productsavebefore.php
```

---

```
<?php

namespace Learning\HelloPage\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Productsavebefore implements ObserverInterface
{    
    protected $authSession;

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession)
    {
        $this->authSession = $authSession;
        $admin_user_id = $this->authSession->getUser()->getId();

        $_product = $observer->getProduct();  // get product object
        //set the the attribute vale
        $_product->setAttribute(admin_user_id, $admin_user_id) ?? what to do here?
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php

namespace Learning\HelloPage\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Productsavebefore implements ObserverInterface
{    
    protected $authSession;

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession)
    {
        $this->authSession = $authSession;
        $admin_user_id = $this->authSession->getUser()->getId();

        $_product = $observer->getProduct();  // get product object
        //set the the attribute vale
        $_product->setAdminUserId($admin_user_id);
    }       
}
```

But you can save the product attribute while editing the product in backend itself.

Comment: my frontname label for the attribute is 'admin_user_id' so what would it be?
like $_product->setadmin_user_id($id)

Comment: No. It will be $_product->setAdminUserId('yourvalue');

Comment: its not working, and keeps loading the page and give the memory allocation error

Comment: check now. I have edited my answer. I removed $_product->save().  Since it is a product save observer, $_product->save() makes a recursive call which leads to memory allocation error.

Comment: got this error
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_int` (`entity_id`,`attribute_id`,`value`,`store_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `entity_id` = VALUES(`entity_id`), `attribute_id` = VALUES(`attribute_id`), `value` = VALUES(`value`), `store_id` = VALUES(`store_id`)

Comment: do u have any alternative way except observer