# How to sort display products by product name in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want to display the products in order if the product has more spaces then it will be displayed first. How can I do it using addAttributeToFilter or setOrder?

For example, product 1 has 10 spaces + product name
product 2 has 12 spaces + product name then product 2 will be displayed first.

Answer (score 0):

`SetOrder` and `addAttributeToFilter` only works with attributes.
You can't achieve what you want with these methods. So what you need to do is load the full collection.
Count the spaces number for each of your project name, and then re-order your collection using the spaces number you stored.

It's adding lots of complexity I think and the request seems odd...are you sure you really want to order with this rule ?

Comment: Sometimes you have to create a little madness for yourself to grow.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the complexity in this you can try another approach.
Create a product attribute "[`space_count`](https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/add-new-product-attribute/)" and create an observer of [`catalog_product_save_before`](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/192125/magento-2-how-to-set-custom-product-attribute-value-on-product-save) and then update the space count in that, and on the listing page where you want to sort the products sort with the attribute "`space_count`".

Breaking a task into subtasks always solves the complexity issue, and I support the madness, which keeps us interested.